# Import Java classes in own Android-Studio project from an existing android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import, project

How can import and make use of classes from another Android Project in my own, without having to change all imports and project paths manually? I want to leave the external project as is and refer to it from another package. How do i make Android-Studio recognize the package? I cannot access and import classes when i tried to add it as a module.

Comment: Add the imported module as a dependency for your project, import alone won't work

Answer (score 0):

Open the 2 project in android studio side by side and copy class from the android studio and paste to another android studio. It will automatically change package name of top.